# Activity To Fragment Migration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to make a menu drawer inside a fragment. I don't know how to write a snippet, and would like your help to translate the code from activity into a fragment

Fragment

```
class ChartFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentChartBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentChartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
        
        
        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

---

Activity code(fragment):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 
   
val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
                val lines = readCSV(uri)
                val newEntries = lines.map { line -> toEntry(line) }.groupingBy { entry -> entry.x }
                    .reduce { _, accumulator, element -> if (accumulator.y > element.y) accumulator else element }.values
                val vl = LineDataSet(newEntries.toList().take(4000), "cost")
                vl.setDrawValues(false)
                vl.setDrawFilled(true)
                vl.lineWidth = 1.5f
                vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
                vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red
                vl.setDrawCircles(false)
                binding.lineChart.data = LineData(vl)
                binding.lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)
                binding.lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
                binding.lineChart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
                binding.lineChart.isScaleYEnabled = false
                binding.lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
            }
            binding.btnLoadCsv.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                intent.type = "text/*"
                getContent.launch("text/*")
            }
            val markerView = CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker_view)
            binding.lineChart.marker = markerView
    
            _binding = FragmentChartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            return binding.root
        }
    
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun readCSV(uri: Uri?): List<String> {
            if (uri != null) {
                val csvFile = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                val isr = InputStreamReader(csvFile)
                return BufferedReader(isr).readLines()
            }
            return Collections.emptyList()
        }
    
        private fun toEntry(line: String): Entry {
            val split = line.split(";")
            val time = split[1]
            // idx 01234 012345 l:5 lub 6
            // val 84504 165959
            // 0, 3 - 845
            val secondsStartIdx = time.length - 2
            val minutesStartIdx = time.length - 4
            val hoursStartIdx = (time.length - 6).coerceAtLeast(0)
    
            val hour = time.substring(hoursStartIdx, hoursStartIdx + time.length - 4)
            val minutest = time.substring(minutesStartIdx, minutesStartIdx + 2)
            val seconds = time.substring(secondsStartIdx, secondsStartIdx + 2)
    
            val newTime =
                hour.toFloat() * 10000 + (minutest.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt() * 100 + (seconds.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt()
            return Entry(newTime, split[2].toFloat())
}
```

---

ChartLayout

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.chart.ChartFragment"
        android:id="@+id/chart_layout">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:padding="9dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLoadCsv"
            android:text="@string/load"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Comment: What do you exactly need ? Do you want to know the exact way of creating a menu in a Fragment ? Or you are facing any issue in migrating your code from activity to fragment ? Be more specific .

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I have a problem with code migration

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar are you help me??

Comment: I want to help you , but cannot because you have not mentioned exactly what you want . Mention what is the issue you are facing exactly also add more code if possible ]

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I just want to put the code from activity into the fragment, I also gave the fragment layout

Comment: One last thing add your whole activity class too

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I added all the activity

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar are you help me??

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar pls help me ????? you now who help me

Comment: I understand . I am bit busy . I will surely help you out , once I am free . Please have patience . Till then keep learning about the concepts of Fragment and Activity .

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Thannk you very much!

Comment: I am also stuck while trying to solve this . Will keep trying and let you know